# Upload a photo from camera to PHP server

Tags: php, android, image, upload

The end result is that I want to upload selected photos from and Android phone  to a php website.

I can display the images from the camera and get the filename that I want to upload.  However I cannot use FileInputStream on the file name because it is not private to my application. Use FileInputStream generates an error that the file contains a path separater.

Does anyone know how to get the filestream running?  Do I have to copy the file into a private file store?

Comment: What are you using on the client side? FileInputStream does not ring a bell with regards to PHP.

Comment: sounds like Java, maybe you could post the exact error you get and don't forget to retag your question if it's about java.

Comment: I've discovered that if I cannot Google the answer -- or even a hint of one -- to my seemingly obvious problem, I'm probably asking the wrong question.

Comment: check this article, [http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/). It works.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [this blog post](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html)?  How about [this discussion thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e51d4f74452a1143?tvc=2&pli=1)?  Is [this one](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/upload-files-to-web-server-t443-75.html) useful?

Are you perhaps pigeonholing yourself into a particular solution, where another might exist?